# React Boilerplate : Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: babeljs, antd, react-boilerplate, babel-polyfill

I am getting the error of `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` because of the following reason :

```
npm.babel.e5824bbfde6f57781e4f.chunk.js:1 @babel/polyfill is loaded more than once on this page. This is probably not desirable/intended and may have consequences if different versions of the polyfills are applied sequentially. If you do need to load the polyfill more than once, use @babel/polyfill/noConflict instead to bypass the warning.
```

It only happens when I build for production using `npm run build` command and serve those files with `http-server` or `serve`.

I had integrated React-Boilerplate with antd Theme and I had to change in the configuration in webpack though it's working as expected on development mode but throwing error  when build for production.

Comment: Any public git repo to check for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I was using a third party library https://github.com/onfido/onfido-sdk-ui which was causing that issue.

As I had removed that library and run the production build again it's working perfectly fine.